# Yii2 Submitting multiple forms

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I was wondering if once I press the submitButton I could send all the data to the Controller. With the code bellow I only receive data from $modelForm3, all other models ($modelform1 and $modelForm2) are blanks.
Because of validation before pressing the next button I need multiple forms.

```
<fieldset>
       <?php $form1 = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
          <form id="msform1">
              <?= $form1->field($modelForm1, 'Name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "Name1"]); ?>
          <?= $form1->field($modelForm1, 'Surname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "Surname1"]); ?>
              <?= $form1->field($modelForm1, 'City')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "City1"]); ?>
          </form>
       <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    //next button
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
       <?php $form1 = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
          <form id="msform2">
              <?= $form1->field($modelForm2, 'Name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "Name2"]); ?>
          <?= $form1->field($modelForm2, 'Surname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "Surname2"]); ?>
              <?= $form1->field($modelForm2, 'City')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "City2"]); ?>
          </form>
      <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    //next button
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
       <?php $form1 = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
          <form id="msform3">
              <?= $form1->field($modelForm3, 'Name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "Name3"]); ?>
          <?= $form1->field($modelForm3, 'Surname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "Surname3"]); ?>
              <?= $form1->field($modelForm3, 'City')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => "City3"]); ?>
              <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
          </form>
       <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Use one form and remember next button and validate that part only or use ajax validate or save parts of form.